# Magento 1.9 Save action for Catalog Product custom tab

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, catalog, controllers, save

I created the custom tab in Catalog Product.
It is my `layout/labels.xml`

```
<adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
    <reference name="product_tabs">
         <action method="addTab"><name>labels</name><block>productlabels/adminhtml_products_edit_tabs_labels</block></action>
    </reference> 
</adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
```

And Tab.

```
class Vendor_ModuleName_Block_Adminhtml_Products_Edit_Tabs_Labels 
extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form implements 
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface
{
protected function _prepareForm()
{
    //$model = Mage::registry('product_labels');
    $model = Mage::getModel('productlabels/block')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('product_page_image', ["notnull" => 'product_page_image'])->getData();
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
    $fieldset = $form->addFieldSet('label_form', array(
        'legent' => Mage::helper('productlabels')->__('Labels'),));

    foreach ($model as $value) {
        $fieldset->addField('label_' . $value['id_label'], 'checkbox', array(
            'label' => $value['title'],
            'name' => $value['id_label'],
            'value' => 1,
            'after_element_html' => '<p style="margin-top: 5px"><img style="max-width: 200px" src="'.Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . $value['product_page_image'] . '"></p>',
        ));
    }

    $form->setValues($model);
    $this->setForm($form);
    return parent::_prepareForm();
}

public function canShowTab()
{
    return true;
}

public function getTabLabel()
{
    return $this->__('Product Labels');
}

public function getTabTitle()
{
    return $this->__('Product Labels');
}

public function isHidden()
{
    return false;
}
```

**How can i save data from this tab in DB?**. I try create in `Namespace/Module/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php` **saveAction()**, but it remove native action.

Comment: you need to override the core controller `Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php`

Comment: i can`t extend this class

Comment: you have to or you can use observer for event product save

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of overriding controller action, you should use events and observer feature of Magento.

Please try to observe **`catalog_product_save_before`** event and write an observer function to save the data.

Comment: Yes, but i find other ways

Answer (score 0):

> How can i save data from this tab in DB?. I try create in
>   Namespace/Module/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php
>   saveAction(), but it remove native action.

If this happens you will have to override properly. Correct class name for override would be Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController. To extend original method code you should call saveAction from parent class.

```
public function saveAction()
{
     // your custom code goes here

     parent::saveAction();
}
```

> Beware! Overriding core classes is considered a bad technique and will
>   potentially increase further code maintenance. Use Event Observers whenever it is possible.

Comment: Warning: include(Mage\Adminhtml\Catalog\ProductController.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in D:\xampp\htdocs\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 94

Comment: magento can not autoload the class of the rewritten controller.

require_once "Mage/Adminhtml/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php";

is needed on top of rewritten class